# How can I connect to a server and index pdf files with elastic Search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, vaadin

So I have a basic User interface I created with vaadin and the goal is to eventually have an web application that I will deploy. This application will allow users to Search, update , delete/create, add, files to folders containing pdfs that  that will be indexed and categorized. In other words I'm dealing with pdfs that need to be found and open after the user's query no matter what category is present or later added dynamically by the user. There isn't much information on using Spring boot ,elastic search, and vaadin .(plus I'm still a noob ) so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Hello PG007, vaadin is running on the server, the UI in the webbrowser. Which folders do you wish to scan for PDFs? The server folders (works) or the folders on the client computer (Does not work since the vaadin server does not have access to the folders on the client computer)?

Comment: hey @Andre' Schild , 1st off thanks for the help. The issue is that all the folders (with PDFs) that I hope to index ,scan,and query is on a different PC. the application i wanted to deploy must give access  or map to a drive (which contains the PDFs). So are u saying vaadin cant be configured in this way?

Comment: This has nothing to do with vaadin. Communication via between server and webbworser is always http/https. So you either give the server access to the clients drive by some kind of cifs/nfs/.. share, or you have to transfer(upload) the files to the server. Perhaps if you explain your usecase in more details we could think about another solution

Comment: mmm interesting well allow  me give another shot of explaining this.  Vaadin and its purpose is to generate my U.I  for this  pdf file search engine Project. The U.I or front end that is generated by vaadin will allow the user to create,rename,update and delete new categories to search for Pdf's by individual categories or all the categories.. After doing some research today i realize I need to understand 1 of the 3 technologies to link with U.I  elastic search, solr, tiki. These technologies have pros/cons and i need figure out a way to implement and index dynamically so scale isn't a issue

Comment: When your vaadin server is running on the same system as the PDF's are localed, then it works. Otherwise not (But has nothing to do with vaadin)

Comment: OK that makes sense . your right it has nothing to do with vaadin. The underlying  Issue is the folder with pdf files aren't on the same system . With that being said  I need to reformulate the concepts associated with this search engine idea or find away to make everything local. As for a general web application question  what route should i take on deploying   java web applications that everyone at work can access through a browser?

Comment: There is no general work-for-all solution. When working with a webbrowser, the logic is usually executed serverside and only the GUI part is on the client side (No matter if C#, Java, PHP etc.) As long as you don't need to access resources from the endusers (webbrowser) point of view this works fine. But when you need to access resources from the webbrowser point of view, you are very very limited (Security is the main issue)

Comment: so I have the security issue figured out. I spoke with the network engineer. So the other vaadin/java question I have and might post later is : Is there a way for me to create some sort of for loop that works with vaadin to create  check box U.I object for every folder that is  . for example say on my windows machine I have a 3 folders (with  pdf's)  A, B, and C all on  local drive C. With the loop i want vaadin to to create3 check box's A, B, and C as well as carry over the name to the U.I. I have psuedo code that needs to be refined to match  API's but i just wanna make sure before I try.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch provide a plugin based on [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to help you to index PDF named [Mapper plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-attachments.html) (former mapper-attachment)
If you want to use Spring (not especially Spring boot), you can use Spring Data ElasticSearch but not sure that it's available for 5.X version. From my side, I prefere build my own Client API (Java) based on ElasticSearch Java API to fit my needs. I don't know vaadin....